# How to run Unix shell script in a java code using ExpectJ tool?

Tags: java, linux, shell, expect, expectj

**This is my hello.sh shell script**

```
VALID_NAME="abcd"

echo "Name: "

read name

if [ "$name" == $VALID_NAME ]; then

echo "correct"

else

echo "unexpected input"

fi
```

========================================================

**This is my Java code**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import expectj.*;

public class Trial {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ();
    String command = "sh /root/Desktop/hello.sh";
    Spawn s;
    try {
        s = exp.spawn(command);
        s.expect("Name: ");
        s.send("abcd");
        System.out.println(s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
        s.stop();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ExpectJException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
}
```

======================================================================

**And this is my OUTPUT**

Name:  //this is wat it asks for

abcd   //this is what i give..and nothing happens

============================================================

I've corrected my java code above..

Comment: If ExpectJ is like vanilla Expect, you have to send a carriage return: `s.send("abcd\r");`

Comment: @glenn: i don't have much idea about expect either. This is the first time i'm working on expectj. Anyways, i considered your suggestion,but unfortunately that didn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Java code you look for

```
s.expect("VALID_NAME=");
```

yet in your Bash code, you have:

```
echo "Name: "
```

It seems like simply changing your Java code to the following should work:

```
s.expect("Name: ");
```

Comment: @hari Seems to be like you need to use ``getCurrentStandardOutContents()``. And quite possibly also ``expectClose()``. See: http://expectj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html.

Comment: @darhuuk: I've made the changes as u suggested..But no change in the output.

Comment: @hari See DaveHowes comment in the other answer: you're asking ExpectJ for a String, but then don't do anything with it. If you want to show the String, print it: ``System.out.println(s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());``.

Comment: @hari Please upvote and accept my answer in that case. (And I'm sure @DaveHowes will appreciate it as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ExpectJ, but the start of your error message`sh: hello.sh: No such file or directory` suggests that it is unable to find your shell script. Have you tried it with the full path to the script?

```
String command = "sh /root/Desktop/hello.sh";
```

Comment: @darhuuk: thanks..i've made the changes u guys suggested and it worked..but only to an extent..the new problem is its taking the input..but not displaying the corresponding output..M i missing something very silly here??

Comment: A \n here and there, perhaps?

Comment: @Ingo: \n is not the problem here..I think I'm missing some statement..Not sure what that is..

Comment: s.getCurrentStandardOutContents() returns the contents of standard out, but you're not doing anything with it. What happens if you try System.out.println(s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());  ?